# How to use a character '# in string?

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to conncect MSSQL DB to python, and the DB's password has included a character '#'.

Is there any way to use '#' in string, not changing the password?

Comment: Use a "raw string" by including `r` modifier before the string, like so: `r"This#is$my%password"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the character '#' in a string in python programming language by using the escape character ''.

For example:

print("#include <stdio.h>")

You can use the character '#' in a string in Python by putting it inside quotes:

my_string = "This is a string with a # in it

Answer (score 0):

As somebody has already answered the question, you can use `r` modifier for raw
string which will basically ignore the special character string functionalities.

You can also use `fr` modifier as a combination of formatted and raw string in python. Find the below example for your reference.

```
a = 100
raw_string = r"!@#$%^&*()\n\t\\{a}"
formatted_raw_string = fr"!@#$%^&*()\n\t\\{a}"
print("Raw String = ", raw_string)
print("Formatted Raw String = ", formatted_raw_string)
```

Output:
Raw String =  !@#$%^&*()\n\t\{a}

Formatted Raw String =  !@#$%^&*()\n\t\100